# highcharts drag and drop event binding

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts, drag-and-drop

I have a highchart with two plotlines and one plotband extending between these two plotlines. I have added drag and drop events to all three (thanks to http://jsfiddle.net/48awM/30/, found via another answer here).

When I drag and drop lines A and B, I want the plotband to be updated such that it still extends between the new positions of A and B. If I do this by removing and adding plotband or updating the axis, I am not able to drag and drop the plotband anymore, the event is not bound to it any longer.

One thing I could do to overcome this is translating the plotband element, but I am not sure how exactly should I mention the translation parameters - for some reason when the translation parameters are generated dynamically based on the drag and drop of plotlines, the translation doesn't happen as expected.

I was wondering if there is a way to remove and add plotband but still maintain the drag and drop ability. This would be particularly useful since I would like to be able to drag and drop the plotband and change the positions of A and B such that they are at the beginning and end of the plotband as well.

My code is as follows.

```
@Component({
selector: 'smooth',
directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES],
styles: [`
chart {
  display: block;
 }
`],
template: `<chart [options]="options" (load)="load($event.context)"></chart>
           `

})



export class AppSmoothComponent 
{ options={
  xAxis:{plotLines:[{value:3,color:'red',width:5,id:'A',label:  {text:'A',rotation:0,x:-18,style:{color:'red',fontWeight:'bold'}}},
                {value:5,color:'red',width:5,id:'B',label:{text:'B',rotation:0,x:+12,style:{color:'red',fontWeight:'bold'}}}],

     plotBands:[{color:'green',from:3,to:5,id:'Band',label:'Band'}]

     },
 series:[{data:[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]}],

      }
 constructor(){}

 draggablePlotLine(axis,plotlineID)

 {

  var clickX,clickY;


  var getPlotLine = function(){
    for(var i=0;i<axis.plotLinesAndBands.length;i++)
    { 
      if(axis.plotLinesAndBands[i].id===plotlineID)
      { 
        return axis.plotLinesAndBands[i]}
      }

   }

    var givenPlotLine = function(plotlineID){
    for(var i=0;i<axis.plotLinesAndBands.length;i++)
    { 
      if(axis.plotLinesAndBands[i].id===plotlineID)
      { 
        return axis.plotLinesAndBands[i]}
      }

   }

   var getValue=function(){
          var plotLine=getPlotLine();
          var translation=plotLine.svgElem.translateX;
          var new_value=axis.toValue(translation)-axis.toValue(0)+plotLine.options.value;
          new_value=Math.max(axis.min,Math.min(axis.max,new_value));
          return new_value; 
    }

  var getLabel=function(){
     var plotLine=getPlotLine();
     var label=plotLine.options.label;
     return label;
  }


   var drag_start = function(e){

    $(document).bind({
      'mousemove.line':drag_step,
      'mouseup.line':drag_stop
    })

    var plotLine=getPlotLine();

    clickX=e.pageX-plotLine.svgElem.translateX;
   }

   var drag_step = function (e) {

       var plotLine = getPlotLine();
       var label=plotLine.options.label;
       var new_translation = e.pageX - clickX ;
       var new_value;
       if(plotlineID=='Band'){new_value=axis.toValue(new_translation) - axis.toValue(0);
                             new_value = Math.max(axis.min, Math.min(axis.max, new_value));
                             new_translation = axis.toPixels(new_value + axis.toValue(0));
                             }
       else {

      new_value = axis.toValue(new_translation) - axis.toValue(0) + plotLine.options.value;
      new_translation = axis.toPixels(new_value + axis.toValue(0) - plotLine.options.value);}

       plotLine.svgElem.translate(new_translation,0);


       };

  var drag_stop = function () {
        $(document).unbind('.line');

        var plotLine = getPlotLine();

        var plotLineOptions = plotLine.options;
        console.log(plotLineOptions);

        var label=plotLine.label;
        //Remove + Re-insert plot line
        //Otherwise it gets messed up when chart is resized
        if (plotLine.svgElem.hasOwnProperty('translateX')) {

            if(plotlineID=='Band'){ 
              axis.removePlotBand(plotLineOptions.id);
              axis.addPlotBand(plotLineOptions); 
                                  }
            else{
            plotLineOptions.value = getValue()
            axis.removePlotLine(plotLineOptions.id);
            axis.addPlotLine(plotLineOptions); 
            console.log(axis.plotLinesAndBands[2]);
            if(plotlineID=='A')
            {var Boptions=givenPlotLine('B')
             console.log(Boptions);
             axis.removePlotBand('Band');
               axis.addPlotBand({from:plotLineOptions.value,to:Boptions.options.value,id:'Band'                 ,color:'green'})}
            else if(plotlineID=='B')
              {console.log(plotLineOptions.value,axis.plotLinesAndBands[0].options.value)
            var Aoptions=givenPlotLine('A')
            axis.removePlotBand('Band');
            axis.addPlotBand({from:Aoptions.options.value,to:plotLineOptions.value,id:'Band',color:'green'});
            }
            }
        }



    getPlotLine().svgElem
            .css({'cursor': 'pointer'})
            .translate(0, 0)
            .on('mousedown', drag_start);



        };

   drag_stop();


  }

  load(instance) {
  this.draggablePlotLine(instance.xAxis[0],'A');
  this.draggablePlotLine(instance.xAxis[0],'B');
  this.draggablePlotLine(instance.xAxis[0],'Band');

  console.log('ready');

   }


   }
```

P.S: The drag and drop of plotband is not working correctly in the above code. Also this assumes that A is always to the left of B.

Comment: I am wondering about translating your plotBand. Is the 'translation doesn't happen as expected' error occurring as well when you are translating your plotBand manually (using hardcoded values)?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Grzegorz Blachliński. The plot band can be translated normally if it is hardcoded, but the problem in applying that here is this - the width of the plotband is not a constant when you move one of the plotlines. If the plotband existed from 2 to 3 and I moved line A to 1, I want the plotband to exist from 1 to 3. If I translated it, it would go to 1 to 2. If I update the from and to parameters, I can no longer drag and drop.